# How can I validate my .vimrc?

Tags: macos, vim, vimrc

My .vimrc files seems to work, and doesn't generate any visible errors during normal operation. I recently started using Knife, and found that I cannot use Vim as my editor for editing Chef content because something is causing it to exit with a bad code. Removing the .vimrc file made Knife happy, so I'm assuming that something in my .vimrc is bad.

Are there any commands or tools that I can use to check the .vimrc itself for errors?

This is the vimrc in question:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'michalbachowski/vim-wombat256mod'
Bundle 'spf13/vim-autoclose'
Bundle 'leshill/vim-json'
Bundle 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Bundle 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-markdown'
Bundle 'beyondwords/vim-twig'
Bundle 'spf13/PIV'
Bundle 'othree/html5-syntax.vim'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/HTML-AutoCloseTag'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/indenthtml.vim'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline'
" Keep bundle commands between here and filetype plugin indent on.



filetype plugin indent on     " required

" Brief help
" :BundleList          - list configured bundles
" :BundleInstall(!)    - install (update) bundles
" :BundleSearch(!) foo - search (or refresh cache first) for foo
" :BundleClean(!)      - confirm (or auto-approve) removal of unused bundles
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" NOTE: comments after Bundle commands are not allowed.

" NERDTree config
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
autocmd vimenter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif

" enable paste mode
nnoremap <F2> :set invpaste paste?<CR>
set pastetoggle=<F2>
set showmode

" Set PHP debugger port to 9001
let g:debuggerPort = 9001

set t_Co=256
colorscheme wombat256mod
:syntax enable

python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python powerline_setup()
python del powerline_setup
set rtp+=/Users/shane/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/bindings/vim

set number              " Enables line numbers
set cindent             " autoindent
set tabstop=4           " set tab distance
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab           " force tabs into spaces
set ruler

let g:html_indent_script1 = "inc"
let g:html_indent_style1 = "inc"

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead Gemfile set filetype=ruby
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead Vagrantfile set filetype=ruby
```

Comment: Are the lines `Jeeves:chef shane$ vi /Users/shane/.vimrc` and `Jeeves:chef shane$ cat /Users/shane/.vimrc` actually part of your vimrc file, or are they a careless cut-and-paste from your terminal?

Comment: Just a careless copy. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  As with most (all?) interpreted languages, only thing that can be done is checking for syntactic validity, but whether the function calls etc. you wrote down make any sense at all, only shows when the specific code path is actually hit.

Only thing you can do is narrow the problem down by examining *what* is the »bad code« and what it's trying to tell you.  You could for example try to debug the problem by commenting all things of which you are not perfectly sure they don't cause your problem, try whether Knife works with this configuration and iteratively enable the previous commented out code until you get the error again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is vim's exit code, and not the status of the file you are editing?  Under `:help 'backupcopy'` there is a paragraph on iusing vim to edit your crontab file.  You can get there directly (but lose context) with `:help crontab`:

```
                 *crontab*
One situation where "no" and "auto" will cause problems: A program
that opens a file, invokes Vim to edit that file, and then tests if
the open file was changed (through the file descriptor) will check the
backup file instead of the newly created file.  "crontab -e" is an
example.
```

If this might be what is going on with Knife, then try adding `:set bkc=yes` to your vimrc file.  You may save yourself a lot of testing, since no matter how much you comment out in your vimrc file, vim will reset the `'compatible'` option as soon as it finds a vimrc file, and this will set `'backupcopy'` to "auto".  I have the following in my vimrc file:

```
" When vim is called from "crontab -e" we need to set this option specially:
au BufEnter /private/tmp/crontab.* setl backupcopy=yes
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for Knife. It was worth trying first though.